# Problemas com Orientation no Datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Estou com problemas em fazer o datepicker 'abrir' para baixo.

Segue os parametros do datepicker que estou usando.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
   todayBtn: "linked",
   forceParse: false,
   autoclose: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   language: 'pt-BR',
   zIndexOffset: 99999999,
   orientation: 'bottom'
});
```

Em algumas telas o zIndexOffset até resolveu o meu problema, porém em outras o campo continua "abrindo" para cima.

Tenho casos que removendo o parâmetro orientation, o calendário "abre" abaixo do campo, e incluindo o parâmetro orientation: 'bottom', o calendário é apresentado acima do campo.

Ex.:

Correto seria... (Sem parâmetro orientation)

[image: Sem parâmetro orientation]

Errado... (Com parâmetro orientation: 'bottom')

[image: Com parâmetro orientation: 'bottom']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quer que o `DatePicker` seja visualizado abaixo do `input`, deves usar:

```
orientation: 'top'
```

Caso queira que o `DatePicker` seja visualizado acima do `input`, deves usar:

```
orientation: 'bottom'
```

A regra é essa, o parâmetro `bottom` é em relação ao `input`. Significa que o `input` ficará como `bottom`. Veja um [exemplo aqui](http://output.jsbin.com/gudas/2/).

Comment: Obrigado @acklay. Pouco antes de você responder, alterei e vi isso. "Noobada" minha.

Comment: @RafaelWeber normal! Acontece! =D abs